# PowerShell - Exit ForEach-Object after 10 records

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

How can I exit from this script after 10 records?

```
Get-Queue | Get-Message | Suspend-Message

$MailExport = Get-Message

$MailExport | ForEach-Object {$temporary="C:\queuexport\"+$_.fromaddress+"_"+$_.subject+".eml"; export-message $_.identity | assemblemessage -path $temporary}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `Select`'s parameter `-First`.

```
$MailExport | Select -First 10 | ForEach-Object {$temporary="C:\queuexport\"+$.fromaddress+""+$.subject+".eml"; export-message $.identity | assemblemessage -path $temporary}
```

This will only pass the first 10 objects to the `ForEach-Object` Cmdlet.

Comment: How I can export all mail from user mailbox to eml files?